# Create database link-SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, ora-00933

I have a script to create database link as following. But the script encounter error`ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

`CREATE DATABASE LINK "MIG_61_TO_74"
   CONNECT TO "ABC_DEV" IDENTIFIED BY 'ABC_DEV'
   USING 'info001:1521/orcl';`

Comment: `IDENTIFIED BY 'ABC_DEV'` remove quotations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the are apostrophies confusing the parser.
[This example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm) by Oracle doesn't include them, try it that way.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK MIG_61_TO_74
   CONNECT TO ABC_DEV IDENTIFIED BY "ABC_DEV"
   USING 'info001:1521/orcl';
```

Comment: Yes, the apostrophies confused!

Comment: If that answered your question, please mark my answer as "helpful". Thank you.

Comment: As `ABC_DEV` is the password you should enclose it by double quotes, i.e. `"ABC_DEV"`, otherwise it will not be case-sensitive.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Corrected. Thanks.